# Do kaafir have to get his head shaved when he becomes a muslim?

Tags: conversion, hair

Do kaafir have to his head shaved when he becomes a muslim?

Answer (score 2):

No. 
There is no relation between head shaving and converting to Islam. It is simply a personal choice.